# How do I change the tool tip color in highchart?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am trying to change the tool tip background color.This is how it looks at present.[image: Tornado Chart]

The formatter function i used is

```
     tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        enabled: true,
        //backgroundColor: null,
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false,
        formatter: function () {
            var value = '<div style="background-color:red;"><span><b>Market Performance<span style=\'padding-left:50px\'>' + this.x + '</span></b><br/> ' + this.series.name + '$' + this.y + '</span><div>';
            return value;

        },
},
```

I want the tool tip background color to be the series color.Also please suggest me how to fill the div because as shown in the image the div is half filled with red.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cwnf6a4a/ ?

Comment: Can we achieve tool tip in the way like Series is in blue hence the entire tool tip is in blue.Series is in black hence the entire tool tip is in black.I have edited Nighisha John answer below where you can find screenshots.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s5m0ut0p/ Seems to realise your functionality, let me know if is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change your formatter function into

```
   tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        enabled: true,
        backgroundColor: null,
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false,
        formatter: function () {
            var value = '<div style="background-color:'+ this.series.color+';padding:10px"><span><b>Market Performance<span style=\'padding-left:50px\'>' + this.x + '</span></b><br/> ' + this.series.name + '$' + this.y + '</span><div>';
            return value;
        }
}
```

Here is the example [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nighisha/cobrqkfk/)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tooltip.formatter to customise content of tooltip and trigger attr() function on SVG tooltip element. This function allows manipulate on attributes of shapes.

```
formatter: function() {
    var color = this.color;

    this.series.chart.tooltip.label.attr({
      'fill': color
    });

    var value = '<span><b>Market Performance<span style=\'padding-left:50px\'>' + this.x + '</span></b><br/> ' + this.series.name + '$' + this.y + '</span>';
    return value;

  },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fqcpd32f/